# Is it possible to know when I am in a retry attempt?

Tags: sidekiq

Say I am sending out emails using sidekiq, I want to know if my worker is currently running in a retry attempt after failing previously?

Say I send 3 emails based on event that happen in my application:

```
Event1
Event2
Event3
```

Now if for some reason my sidekiq job fails sending the email for Event1.  And now Event#2 or Event#3 have occurred, when sidekiq tries to retry I want to know the job is retrying so I can skip sending the email.

Is it possible to know from within sidekiq if it is running with retry > 0?

Answer (score -1):

Your three emails should be sent as three separate jobs.

Comment: Yes but if the Event#1 job failed, and now the workflow is already at Event#2, when the job for event#1 retries I want to be able to NOT send the email since I am at event#2 now, get it?